# Change Date/Timestamp Format from Excel object datatype to Pandas Dataframe (String)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have managed to extract a specific cell from the Excel but now I have gotten this instead:

**2020-01-30T00:00:00.000000000**

I removed the characters after the 'T' by using split function:

```
d1 = d.str.split("T",n=1, expand=True)[0]
```

and the result is:
**2020-01-30**

My question is how do I change the date format to dd/mm/yyyy.

I am aware of the strftime function by I failed to get a result from that. The errors always show that the series does not have series attribute or date.datetime is not an attribute of the string.

Here is the working code:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    import datetime

    df = pd.read_csv('test1.xlsx',
    #header=None,
    #names = headers,
    dtype = dtypes,
    parse_dates = pdate, 
    date_parser=None) 


    d = df['AA']
    d1 = d.str.split("T",n=1, expand=True)[0]
    d2 = d1[0]

    print(d2)

              AA  Num
    0 2020-01-01    5
    1 2020-02-01   10
    2 2020-03-01   15
    3 2020-04-01   20
    4 2020-05-01   25
```

Answer (score 0):

First idea is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['AA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['AA'])
```

If need remove values after `T` your solution should be changed to:

```
df['AA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['AA'].str.split("T").str[0])
```

Comment: But the date structure remains the same after splitting the string just before 'T'. I want it to be "%d/%m/%Y"

Comment: @SyahmiShaarani - Not understand, `2020-01-01` format is wrong?

Comment: I have splitted the string to be like that. Now, I want the year to be at the last, not in front. It has to be '01-01-2020' instead of 2020-01-01'

Comment: @SyahmiShaarani - OK, so use `df['AA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['AA'].str.split("T").str[0]).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` - but it is strings, not datetimes

Comment: @SyahmiShaarani - If want datetimes, is not possible custom format, always datetimes are in python `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Answer (score 0):

I have used your examples to create a dataframe and following are the answer:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
```

Then I created the dataframe.

```
data = {'date': ['2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000','2020-02-01T00:00:00.000000000','2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000','2020-04-01T00:00:00.000000000','2020-05-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
        'num':[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'num'])
```

Now, the answer part:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

for four digit year to be shown, you need to pass capital 'Y'. And you need to use dt.strftime to work.

```
       date     num
0   01/01/2020  5
1   01/02/2020  10
2   01/03/2020  15
3   01/04/2020  20
4   01/05/2020  25
```

if you want to change the format of your date column you can use the following line of code.

```
df['date'].astype(str)
```

This will convert the whole column as object.

Comment: Hello but what if the data is too long, would it possible to create the df without listing everything in the 'data' variable?

Comment: This 'data' dictionary I created to show as an example and converted it into dataframe,  You are already reading the xslx file to a dataframe. You don't need to create data variable. You can proceed from the answer part.